# How to run multiple supporting apps (tomcat) on my local mac which I don't modify?

Tags: tomcat, docker, chef-infra

I work on app A. In order for me to work in app A, I depend on multiple apps B, C and D. (All of them runs on tomcat).

I had to build and run my app A, but not necessarily apps B, C & D. 
So is there a easy way to spin up apps B, C & D WITHOUT having to manually build and run each one of them every time i start working on my app A.

Answer (score 0):

There are of lots of ways to launch applications without building them but your question is overly vague so specific recommendations are hard. Build JARs for the apps on a CI server and push them to a tool like Artifactory or Nexus and then have the Chef code pull from there?